# VBA: Get specific column from webpage using seleniumbasic

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get a specific columns data which is in a form of table in a webpage to my excel file using VBA, I'm good at opening webpage and log-in and navigate to table area but I'm unable to get the **specific columns from the table**. I don't have idea to pull only a column from table with in the web page.

I use chrome for the automation. Below is the sample Html code for your reference.

```html
<table class="Performed-Detailes-Mac">
                        <thead class="table-head-basic">
                            <tr>
                                <th>File</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Wait 1</th>
                                <th>Wait 2</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th class="text-right">Machines</th>
                                <th class="text-right">Usage</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr class="table-row">
                                <td data-bind="text: id">File12</td>
                                <td data-bind="text: Name">JCB</td>
                                <td data-bind="text: Date">02/01/2022</td>
                                <td data-bind="text: check1">10:55 </td>
                                <td data-bind="text: check2">12:30</td>
                                <td data-bind="text: Status">Completed</td>
                                <td class="text-right" data-bind="text: Machines">2</td>
                                <td class="text-right" data-bind="text: Str">100 Percent</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="table-row" data-bind="visible : $root.isEditItemsOnDetailsEnabled || $root.Items().length > 0">
              <td class="text-right" data-bind="text: TotalDuration">1.75</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
</table>
```

For reference I have provided only one line (tr) code with header details.
From the above html I would like to extract only "Date" and "Machines"  column details with all rows.

The code which I tried is provided below. I did some here and there in For loop but no luck as of now.

```
Sub GetTable()

Dim Dr As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim hTable, hBody, hTR, hTD, tb As Object
Dim bb, tr, td As Object
    
    Dr.Get "My Webpage Url"
    Dr.Wait 2000
        With Sheet1
            Set hTable = Dr.FindElementsByCss(".Performed-Detailes-Mac")
            For Each tb In hTable
            Set hBody = tb.FindElementsByTag("tbody")
            For Each bb In hBody
            Set hTR = bb.FindElementsByTag("tr")
            For r = 1 To hTR.Count - 2
            Set hTD = hTR(r).FindElementsByTag("td")
            If hTD.Count = 0 Then Set hTD = hTD(r).FindElementsByTag("th")
            Lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            For c = 1 To hTD.Count
            .Cells(Lastrow, c).Value = hTD(c - 1).Text
            Next c
            Next r
            Next bb
            Exit For
            Next tb
        End With
End Sub
```

This is my first query, My apologies if I'm wrong in anywhere.
Thanks Gold

Comment: Could you share the link to the webpage? I would like to be able to test the code while developing since I'm relatively new to `Selenium`.

Comment: @VBasic2008, Thanks for the reply. I don't have right to share the link based on my work environment. Is it not possible to do with the provided html code..

Comment: Team, could any one suggest solution on this question..